# Critical error on Red Hat Linux

Tags: vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel-panic

I have a RHEL 5 x64 virtual machine. My colleague accidentally deleted some main system files related to root as he said.

Now when I boot the machine , I got the following error :

```
exec of init (sbin/init) failed!!! No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init!
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue specially that the machine contains critical data.

Comment: Do a simple reinstall without formatting

Comment: Probably a good idea, but first back and test a backup. (or swap drives, reinstall and then copy data from the drives or restore from the regular backups).